# Access to Sibling element in Playwright

Tags: c#, blazor, e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I have two sibling spans in my DIV. I am doing E2E testing in Blazor and I want to access the second Span content (`@Status`).

```
<div>
     <span> Status:</span>
     <span> @Status</span>
 </div>
```

I found a solution for it, if it was JavaScript according to this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/discussions/10821).

```
const text = await page.locator(':text(" Status:") + span').textContent();
```

However, I am not sure how to do the same for C# syntax. I have access to the first span but not next one.

```
var firstSpan = Page.Locator("text= Status :");
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, JS and C# "syntax" should be identical because you're using a CSS selector syntax either way, in this case.

Answer (score 7):

IMO relative positioning is flaky if there's fluid layout on the page.

`:below()` can switch to `:right-of()` if page css layout changes, eg flexbox.

Is there any reason you don't use simple

```js
// invert double and single quotes for c#
const text = await Page.locator(":text(' @Status:')").textContent();
```

OR you original is perfect with quote marks inverted

```js
const text = await page.locator(":text(' Status:') + span").textContent();
```

---

If you want to use relative layout, `:near()` would be better

```js
await Page.locator("span:near(:text(' Status:'))").first().textContent();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [selecting selectors based on layout](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/selectors#selecting-elements-based-on-layout) for this.

```cs
await page.Locator("span:below(:text(\" Status :\"))").TextContentAsync()
```

Comment: My page contains 50 of spans! the only way I can access the second span is find the first one by text. your solution says go and find the second span in the entire page. correct?