# Get immediate sibling of locator using PlayWright

Tags: c#, playwright, playwright-dotnet

This is the DOM structure:

```html
<div class="row">
  <label class="left">foo</label>
  <label class="right">bar</label>
  <label class="left">baz</label>
  <label class="right">qux</label>
  <label class="left">abc</label>         <!-- I know this -->
  <label class="right">123</label>        <!-- I want this -->
</div>
```

I want the immediate sibling of "`abc`", i.e. `"123"`.

I tried these, but both time out:

```cs
await page.Locator(".row").GetByText("abc").Locator("+ .right").InnerText();

await page.Locator(".row").Locator(":right-of(:text('abc'))").InnerTextAsync();
```

I also tried using `ElementHandle`, without success.

How can I get the immediate sibling of the locator above?

##### UPDATE

As you can see, I already tried the special Playwright syntax `"right-of"` but it times out. **So this is not a dupe of the linked question, which does not work in this case.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access to Sibling element in Playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73240528/access-to-sibling-element-in-playwright)

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks, no it doesn't help. As you can see above I tried that but it does not return the locator. I don't understand why this fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`following-sibling` is the simplest direct way to do it.

This is something which directly can be handled on `xpath` level so no need to find an feature on `playwright` level to keep things simple.

You may use the direct [following-sibling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-following-sibling-in-selenium) xpath like below:

```
//div[@class="row"]//label[contains(.,"abc")]/following-sibling::label[1]
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `abcLocator.Locator("//following-sibling::*[1]")`.

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get exactly the Locator from the current Locator, then this solution may be suitable (in C#)

```
var nextSibling = await currentLocator.EvaluateHandleAsync("el => el.nextElementSibling");
var nextSiblingLocator = page.Locator("xpath=/html" + await nextSibling.EvaluateAsync<string>("el => el.outerHTML"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a testing environment for the DOM so I'm spit balling a little. Does this work?

```
const loc = page.locator(':text("abc") + label').textContent();
```

I am going off the contents of [this](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/discussions/10821) discussion in the github

I have not had good experience using a sibling selector in the latter parts of a chained locator. In my experience the `+` operator works best when part of other existing css locators rather than as part of a chain.